# Parse a text file, extract a string delimited by ", create, insert and substitute the new string

Tags: awk

Parse a text file, extract a string S1 delimited by ", create a new string S2 from the extracted string S1, insert S2 at the top of the text file, substitute the extracted string S1 with the new string S2.

e.g.

```
S1: 
s
S2: 
public static final String (convert S1 to all uppercase) = "s";
i.e.
public static final String S = "s";
```

e.g.
In.txt:

```
{
    put("legalName", "legalName");
    put("operName", "operName");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        put("firstName["+ i + "]", "firstName[" + (i+1) + "]");
        put("lastName["+ i + "]", "lastName[" + (i+1) + "]");
    }   
}
```

Out.txt (desired output):

```
public static final String LEGALNAME = "legalName";
public static final String OPERNAME = "operName";
{
    put(LEGALNAME, LEGALNAME);
    put(OPERNAME, OPERNAME);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        put("firstName["+ i + "]", "firstName[" + (i+1) + "]");
        put("lastName["+ i + "]", "lastName[" + (i+1) + "]");
    }   
}
```

I tried initially:

```
awk -F'"' '
{if ($2 != "" && $2 !~ /\[/) 
{print "public static final String " toupper($2), "= \"" $2 "\";"};}' In.txt
```

Then I modified Ed Morton's awk script below as tst2.awk, which the actual output is getting close to the desired output but still did not get the desired output.
tst2.awk:

```
NR == FNR {
    arr[NR]=$0; 
    tailBeg = 1
    while ( match(substr($0,tailBeg),/"[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*"/) ) {
        strBeg = tailBeg + RSTART
        strLen = RLENGTH - 2
        string = substr($0,strBeg,strLen)
        strings[string]
        locs[FNR] = locs[FNR] RS strBeg " " strLen
        tailBeg += (RSTART + RLENGTH - 1)
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    for ( string in strings ) {
        map[string] = toupper(string)
        printf "public static final String %s = \"%s\";\n", map[string], string
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= length(arr); i++) {
        for ( string in strings ) {
            map[string] = toupper(string)
            text = arr[i]
            gsub("\""string"\"", map[string], text)
        }
        printf "%s\n", text
    }
}
```

```
awk -f tst2.awk In.txt In.txt > Out2.txt
```

The actual output Out2.txt is slightly different from the desired output Out.txt.
There are no delimiter " around the uppercase string in the put operation.

Out2.txt:

```
public static final String LEGALNAME = "legalName";
public static final String OPERNAME = "operName";
{
    put("legalName", "legalName");
    put(OPERNAME, OPERNAME);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        put("firstName["+ i + "]", "firstName[" + (i+1) + "]");
        put("lastName["+ i + "]", "lastName[" + (i+1) + "]");
    }   
}
```

Comment: This might work for you using GNU sed `sed -Ez ':a;s/(.*)"(\w+)", "\2"/public static final String \U\2\E = "\2";\n\1\U\2, \2/;ta' file`

Comment: @  potong, your sed script works! Would you mind explaining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -Ez ':a;s/(.*)"(\w+)", "\2"/public static final String \U\2\E = "\2";\n\1\U\2, \2/;ta' file
```

This sed solution slurps the entire file into memory (command line option `-z`) and the iteratively, from the end to the start of the file, replaces a match as designated and also inserts another line at the start of the file. Thus after the substitution match fails the file has a bunch of inserted lines at the start and for each of those lines a substituted line in the remainder of the file.

The solution uses a loop `:a`, a substitution `s/.../.../` and branch to the loop if the substitution was successful `ta`.

The substitution looks for a pattern match, starting at the end of the file and then works forward to the start of the file. If the substitution command finds a quoted word, followed by a comma, a space and the same quoted word, it inserts a string `public static final String` , followed by the same word uppercased, followed by a space, an `=`, a space, the quoted word ending in a semi-colon, a newline, then the rest of the file up until the match, which it uppercases, followed by a comma, a space and the same uppercased word.

N.B. The solution uses the `-E` command line option to make regexp more pleasant. Also to prevent the `\U` continuing to do its job ad infinitum, the use of `\E` is used to only uppercase a single word.

Comment: Nice approach. Wish I'd thought of going from the bottom of the file to the top - would've made things a whole lot simpler and only required one pass!

Comment: @EdMorton it was wishful thinking on my part, solved an easier problem i.e. how to insert a line and then substitute a line further down and then realised `greed` led me to the right solution.

Comment: Isaac Newton: If I have seen further than others, it is by standing upon the shoulders of giants.

Comment: @potong, your script use the first \U converts the rest of the replacement to uppercase, or until \L or \E occurs.
What is the second \U for? Why there is no \L or \E after it?

Comment: @albertkao9 when we use any case altering metacharactes they only apply to the strings matched in the left hand side of the substitution regexp. Thus the last part of the regexp matchs `"..."` and stops and so will the uppercasing. It is worth noting there is a mis-match in a way that the `e` flag (evaluation) of the substitution command ignores this and applies itself to the whole of the pattern space. An inconvenience that promotes the use of echoing the pattern space  and using command substitution and back references.

Comment: @potong, if there is an extra put operation which includes only one '.' at the last part, how to change your sed script?
e.g. put("test", "the.end");
then the extra output will be: public static final String TEST = "test"; public static final String THE_END = "the.end"; put(TEST, THE_END);

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with a 2-pass approach using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    tailBeg = 1
    while ( match(substr($0,tailBeg),/"[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*"/) ) {
        strBeg = tailBeg + RSTART
        strLen = RLENGTH - 2
        string = substr($0,strBeg,strLen)
        strings[string]
        locs[FNR] = locs[FNR] RS strBeg " " strLen
        tailBeg += (RSTART + RLENGTH - 1)
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    for ( string in strings ) {
        map[string] = toupper(string)
        printf "public static final String %s = \"%s\";\n", map[string], string
    }
}
FNR in locs {
    n = split(locs[FNR],begLens,RS)
    for ( i=n; i>1; i-- ) {
        split(begLens[i],begLen," ")
        strBeg = begLen[1]
        strLen = begLen[2]
        string = substr($0,strBeg,strLen)
        $0 = substr($0,1,strBeg-2) map[string] substr($0,strBeg+strLen+1)
    }
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk In.txt In.txt
public static final String LEGALNAME = "legalName";
public static final String OPERNAME = "operName";
{
    put(LEGALNAME, LEGALNAME);
    put(OPERNAME, OPERNAME);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        put("firstName["+ i + "]", "firstName[" + (i+1) + "]");
        put("lastName["+ i + "]", "lastName[" + (i+1) + "]");
    }
}
```

Regarding `/"[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*"/`, I'm assuming the strings you want to match look like valid C (and many other languages) symbols and so start with a letter or underscore optionally followed by letters, underscores or digits. If that's the wrong assumption then change that regexp.

Regarding appending to `locs[FNR]` and visiting each `locs[FNR]`s contents with `for ( i=n; i>1; i-- ) {` - it doesn't matter in this case but it's usually important in such applications to replace strings starting from the end of the line rather than from the start of the line because if the new string length can be different from the original and you replaced from the start of the line then the saved `strBeg` values would be wrong after the first replacement.

Alternatively, inspired by [@potong's sed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77605593/1745001) reading the file backwards, here is a 1-pass (for awk) solution using any awk plus `tac`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/"[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*"/) ) {
        string = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH - 2)
        map[string] = toupper(string)
        printf "%s%s", substr($0,1,RSTART-1), map[string]
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}
END {
    for ( string in map ) {
        printf "public static final String %s = \"%s\";\n", map[string], string
    }
}
```

```
$ tac In.txt | awk -f tst.awk | tac
public static final String OPERNAME = "operName";
public static final String LEGALNAME = "legalName";
{
    put(LEGALNAME, LEGALNAME);
    put(OPERNAME, OPERNAME);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        put("firstName["+ i + "]", "firstName[" + (i+1) + "]");
        put("lastName["+ i + "]", "lastName[" + (i+1) + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Both solutions are eye-opener!

Comment: @ Ed Morton
I am sorry that I had not checked the output carefully.
There is a small difference between the desired output and actual output.
There are no delimiter " around the uppercase string in the put operation.

Comment: Then best I can tell you'd just change `strBeg-1` to `strBeg` and `strBeg+strLen`  to `strBeg+strLen-1` in `$0 = substr($0,1,strBeg-1) map[string] substr($0,strBeg+strLen)` to consume those extra `"`s. If that's not exactly right then just adjust those numbers by `1` a couple of times til it is.

Comment: Definitely do not do `gsub("\""string"\"", map[string], text)` as I see you wrote now in your question as that can corrupt your output by changing text that shouldn't be changed. The code goes to the trouble of identifying exactly the locations that need to be changed in the second pass using literal string functions - use that information as I did in my script, don't discard that information and use regexp operations instead and so open the door to changing parts of your code that shouldn't be changed.

Comment: I changed strBeg-1 to strBeg and 
strBeg+strLen to strBeg+strLen-1 in 
$0 = substr($0,1,strBeg-1) map[string] substr($0,strBeg+strLen)
as per your comments, but that's not exactly right.
Then I changed strBeg-1 to strBeg+1 and 
strBeg+strLen to strBeg+strLen-1, but that's not exactly right.

Comment: I was adding 1 instead of subtracting in my previous suggestion, I updated my answer now.

Comment: @ Ed Morton, both awk scripts work! Thank you!!!